# Slick (mootools) selector engine documentation

Tags: mootools

Mootools slick selector engine documentation seems kind of sparse / unfriendly.

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Slick/Slick

An example:

Normally i can reach the last child of an element with:

```
$('wrapper').getLast().setStyle('background-color','green');
```

how do i utilize the new slick engine to achieve the same?
And where is the documentation?

Should i just learn CSS3 selectors?

In their example they use $$('p.foo !^')  to get the last child of p class foo whatever that means. (do they mean the last instance of p.foo in the $$ array or the last child of the last element???)

Here i tried to fiddle a bit, the last two doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/XLVr6/1/

Comment: there is no such thing as CSS3 selectors, it's a different thing. Just Level 3 selectors - which is the spec currently implemented by Slick and Sizzle. **the reason** `p.foo !^` works is because that's an actual slick shortcut - `^` is first element, `!` in Slick normally denotes a reverse combinator - so reverse of first is last (ok, previous, technically :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example bellow will select the last child of the element with `id="wrapper`. It will only return one element.

```
$$('#wrapper !^').setStyle('background-color','red');
```

or better way as only one element is needed, as it is faster:

```
document.getElement('#wrapper !^').setStyle('background-color','red');
```

However, if it's written like this where we select the last child of all p-elements on the page with `class="wrapper"`

```
$$('p.wrapper !^').setStyle('background-color','red');
```

Another way to do it is like this, however next example is faster:

```
('someId').getLast().setStyle('background-color','red');
```

As pointed out by Dimitar this is a better (faster) way to do it:

```
document.getElement('#someId :last-child')
```

---

As for your fiddle, the two last selectors should be written like this:

```
$$('#wrapper :last-child').setStyle('background-color','red');
$$('#wrapper !^').setStyle('background-color','red');
```

Please note the space between "wrapper" and ":last-child", that is because we are selecting the last child of a the child elements of "wrapper".

Comment: this is not exactly correct re: performance in browsers with QSA. they will be faster than chaining, always. http://jsfiddle.net/XLVr6/3/ - personally, I get in FF: `qsa_reverse_last: 69ms`, `qsa_last_child: 40ms`, `id_and_get_last: 191ms` and chrome `qsa_reverse_last: 18.000ms`, `qsa_last_child: 11.000ms`, `id_and_get_last: 49.000ms`. The bigger the dom is, the slower `.getLast()` will be. in old IE, this will be faster. also, you should NOT be using `$$` and applying methods - that returns a collection and does implied `.each`. use `node.getElement()` instead.

Comment: in this 'benchmark' over 2500 iterations of each and a small dom, lower is better (faster). just saying.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm quite suprised that `document.getElement()` is even faster then `document.id().lastChild`. Can you please explain why `document.id().lastChild` is so much slower (or point me in the right direction. Because to my knowlage there should be a real pointer from the parent element to first and last child. On a side note, the fastest selector to get the last child (in my tests) was `'#wrapper :last-child`.